# Accesing subclass method from parent class instance in C++

Tags: c++, oop, custom-data-type

My team and I are working with C++ (OOP paradigm). We have to implement a DataType `DtClassA` and two derived classes `DtClassB` and `DtClassC`.

We did it like this:

```
// DtClassA.h
class DtClassA {
    private:
        int id;

    public:
        DtClassA();
        int getId();
};

// DtClassA.cpp
DtClassA::DtClassA() {
    this->id = 0;
}
int DtClassA::getId() {
    return this->id;
}

// DtClassB.h
class DtClassB: public DtClassA {
    private:
        bool isAlive;

    public:
        DtClassB();
        bool getIsAlive();
}

// DtClassB.cpp
DtClassB::DtClassB() : DtClassA() {
    this->isAlive = true;
}
bool DtClassB::getIsAlive() {
    return this->isAlive;
}

// DtClassC.h
class DtClassC: public DtClassA {
    private:
        char type;

    public:
        DtClassC();
        char getType();
}

// DtClassC.cpp
DtClassC::DtClassC() : DtClassA() {
    this->type = 'm';
}
char DtClassC::getType() {
    return this->type;
}

// main.cpp
int main() {
    DtClassB ctb = DtClassB();
    createA(ctb);
}
createA(DtClassA& dta) {
    cout << dta.getId() << endl; // We can do this.
    cout << dta.getIsAlive();    // We cannot do this.
}
```

In the `main.cpp` file we have to implement the function `createA(DtClassA& dta)`.

This function can receive either a `DtClassB` or `DtClassC`, but in these two cases we cannot access the methods that are not declared in `DtClassA`.

There is some way to access the method `getIsAlive()` inside `createA(DtClassA& dta)` function?

Comment: Sounds like you want [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: you can cast it to the child class with dynamic_cast

Comment: having said that, this is poor design. Having a method that says it takes class A instances and yet does not take them - it only supports B or C is poor design. Better to have an intermediate class derived from A that both B and C are derived from. The intermediate class support isAlive.

Comment: You should use composition. Decatorate `DtClassA` with `DtClassB` and let `DtClassB` expose an accessor to `getId` and implement `bool getIsAlive()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to solve our problem with dynamic_cast (thanks [pm100](https://stackoverflow.com/users/173397/pm100)).

Here the code:

```
// DtClassA.h
class DtClassA {
    private:
        int id;

    public:
        DtClassA();

        // To make a dynamic_cast, we needed to define "getId()" as virtual.
        virtual int getId();
};

// DtClassA.cpp
DtClassA::DtClassA() {
    this->id = 0;
}
int DtClassA::getId() {
    return this->id;
}

// DtClassB.h
class DtClassB: public DtClassA {
    private:
        bool isAlive;

    public:
        DtClassB();
        bool getIsAlive();
}

// DtClassB.cpp
DtClassB::DtClassB() : DtClassA() {
    this->isAlive = true;
}
bool DtClassB::getIsAlive() {
    return this->isAlive;
}

// DtClassC.h
class DtClassC: public DtClassA {
    private:
        char type;

    public:
        DtClassC();
        char getType();
}

// DtClassC.cpp
DtClassC::DtClassC() : DtClassA() {
    this->type = 'm';
}
char DtClassC::getType() {
    return this->type;
}

// main.cpp
int main() {
    DtClassB ctb = DtClassB();
    createA(ctb);
}
createA(DtClassA& dta) {
    cout << dta.getId() << endl; // We can do this.

    try {
        auto dtb = dynamic_cast<ClassB &>(dta);
    } catch (std::bad_cast &e) {
        cout << "Failed to cast DtClassA to DtClassB!" << endl;
    }

    try {
        auto dtc = dynamic_cast<ClassC &>(dta);
    } catch (std::bad_cast &e) {
        cout << "Failed to cast DtClassA to DtClassC!" << endl;
    }

    // In "main()" function we call this function with an instance of
    // DtClassB, so the first try-catch will pass and the second will
    // not.
    // So, now, we can do this:
    cout << dta.getIsAlive();  // getIsAlive() is an operation from DtClassB.
}
```